# What is the difference between ubit16 and uint16 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Some images (for example some DICOMs) are read into Matlab as 'ubit16' precision. What is the difference between a ubit16 and uint16 in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. Both are 16 bit unsigned integers ([source](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#inputarg_precision)).